# WSO2 APIM Metric DB size increasing

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In our production installation, WSO2 APIM 2.0 has been running for past 2 months, we noticed the size of WSO2METRICS_DB h2 database size is constantly increasing. Is currently 1.2 GiB.

Upon checking the content, noticed all data has not been cleaned up since the day it was deployed.

```
sql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM METRIC_GAUGE ;
COUNT(*)
2756204
(1 row, 1 ms)
sql> SELECT MIN(TIMESTAMP) FROM METRIC_GAUGE ;
MIN(TIMESTAMP)
1476859611002 (GMT: Wed, 19 Oct 2016 06:46:51.002 GMT)
(1 row, 3 ms)

sql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM METRIC_METER ;
COUNT(*)
280292
(1 row, 0 ms)
sql> SELECT MIN(TIMESTAMP) FROM METRIC_METER ;
MIN(TIMESTAMP)
1476860091000 (GMT: Wed, 19 Oct 2016 06:54:51 GMT)
(1 row, 2 ms)


sql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM METRIC_TIMER ;
COUNT(*)
1118983
(1 row, 1 ms)
sql> SELECT MIN(TIMESTAMP) FROM METRIC_TIMER ;
MIN(TIMESTAMP)
1476859611002 (GMT: Wed, 19 Oct 2016 06:46:51.002 GMT)
(1 row, 2 ms)

sql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM METRIC_COUNTER ;
COUNT(*)
0
(1 row, 0 ms)

sql>  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM METRIC_HISTOGRAM ;
COUNT(*)
0
(1 row, 0 ms)
```

Can we safely delete old data by timestamp? (say older than a month).

Is there any clean-up task suppose to do this automatically in WSO2?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running APIM 2.0.0 with metrics enabled?

Comment: It is not recommended (by WSO2) to use the flat h2 database files in a production environment. Consider migrating. We use MSSQL Server which allows us to perform cleanup like this automatically.

Comment: Yes, we are running APIM 2.0.0 with metrics enabled. We were not sure if all AM nodes in cluster able to share the db, hence we left it locally. Based on Kjata30's comment, can we confirm that multiple nodes able to access the same DB with no problem (This is 2 node clustered All-in-One configuration).

Comment: Additional question, can we disable this metrics? Will it impact DAS?